# How do I check ActionErrors for a specific error?

Tags: java, validation, struts, struts-1

I'm writing a custom `ActionErrors` message for our application, to display a particular error for a specific circumstance.

```
public class ErrorForm  extends ActionForm{
public ActionErrors validateForm(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request){
errs.add(FORM_KEY_ACTION_TYPE, new ActionMessage(WebGlobals.CUSTOM_ERROR));
return errs;
}
}
```

Unfortunately, the way our code is structured (and I would rather not try to sell "let's restructure four classes for one small change), the `ErrorForm` is a parent to several other classes.  And for reasons other than what I've shown in my code snippets, the validation has to be done in the `ErrorForm` class.

When the parent class terminates, and returns the `ActionErrors` to the child, the child class adds an error message of its own, as shown below.

```
public class ErrorThrowingForm extends ErrorForm {
public ActionErrors postValidate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    ActionErrors errs = super.validateForm(mapping, request);

    if (errs.size() > 0)
    errs.add(WebGlobals.GENERAL_ERROR_KEY, new ActionMessage(WebGlobals.PROP_FIELD_ERROR));

return errs;
}
}
```

Despite the fact that the error message was returned from the parent class, **only the child class's error message is displayed**, and the parent's error message is never seen.  The form field that throws the validation error displays a **!** next to it, but the associated Custom_Error message does not display.

I want to return the custom error message.  And I do not have the ability to just add that error in the children class.

How can I determine what errors are in my `ActionErrors` message, so that I can check for my Custom Error and return it, rather than depending on the children class?

I've already tried simply removing the entire "if" block and returning errs directly as they're received from the `validateForm` method, but when I do, the error message fails to display on the page, and I do not know why.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail *when validation returns to those forms,...*

Comment: @RomanC I've added some more details that will hopefully clear up what I'm talking about - I'm referring to the fact that the Child class calls a method from the parent class, which is supposed to return the ActionErrors of the parent class, but never seems to display the Custom_Message of the parent class when the validation error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent form should be a child of `ValidatorForm` in your terms, that you should better understand. In the child form of your parent you should add `validate` method to invoke validation. Then in the parent implementation you should call framework's super method at the first statement preferably, then   you can add error messages to `ActionErrors` returned by the framework. Hope you understand this.

```
public class ErrorForm  extends ValidatorForm{
public ActionErrors validateForm(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request){
ActionErrors errs= super.validate(mapping, request); 
errs.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage(WebGlobals.CUSTOM_ERROR));
return errs;
}
}
```

Comment: I understand, but unfortunately I can't do that.  The validation has to be done in ErrorForm.  I can't solve this problem by switching the two - ideal though that would be.  I know it's not terribly helpful, but the application structure would make it impossible to switch the two.

Comment: I don't think so, *The validation has to be done in ErrorForm*. Don't you see a code?

Comment: For reasons other than what I've shown in my code snippets, the validation has to be done in the ErrorForm class.  I'm sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Seems you have a problem with the key, try the global message key.

Comment: Ah, it was in fact the Key all along.  Thank you, I hadn't realized my issue until you mentioned that.